# Org mode initial visibility with #+STARTUP

Tags: org-mode, visibility

What is the meaning of the possible values for #+STARTUP?

Comment: Did you consult the documentation for this? If not, try looking in the Org manual (`C-h i`) for `STARTUP`. `i #+STARTUP` takes you to node **In-buffer settings** of the manual. And each individual one is indexed also - e.g., `‘showall’, STARTUP keyword`. You can also use `C-s STARTUP`, repeating `C-s`, to search for `STARTUP` throughout the manual. If you find that the doc is incomplete, incorrect, or unclear, please consider filing a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Yes, I did, as it can be inferred from my answer.
But since I had to consult 3 different places, I decided to create this question to give an answer in just 1 shot.

Comment: Good job. I didn't see your answer when I wrote the comment (I could see only the question while looking at the review queue for new questions). BTW, I submitted bug #[24595](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24595) for the fact that this information is not indexed as well as it should be.

Answer (score 20):

The Org-mode manual indicates these possible values for [initial visibility](https://orgmode.org/manual/Initial-visibility.html#Initial-visibility):

```
#+STARTUP: overview
#+STARTUP: content
#+STARTUP: showall
#+STARTUP: show2levels
#+STARTUP: show3levels
#+STARTUP: show4levels
#+STARTUP: show5levels
#+STARTUP: showeverything
```

With the following meanings, according to the [summary of in-buffer setting](https://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-Settings.html):

```
overview         top-level headlines only
content          all headlines
showall          no folding of any entries
showeverything   show even drawer contents
```

*Bonus*: the Elisp command `describe-variable`, shortcut `C-h v`, shows in the documentation for `org-startup-folded` variable, these two possible values:

```
#+STARTUP: fold              (or `overview', this is equivalent)
#+STARTUP: nofold            (or `showall', this is equivalent)
```